# Is it possible to append data to existing CSV or xlsx file without changing the existing format..using C#?

Tags: c#

I am appending the data to csv file and it works fine. Only thing is when I run the code and open the file I need to adjust the columns and rows to display the data as per original formatting style...

```
Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "," + Title.Text + "," + Participants.Text;
File.AppendAllText(path, Text);
```

Comment: Why are you not adding the data in the "original format" in the first place?

Comment: I think he wants to "auto-detect" the column order in the opened file.

Comment: Data is appended in correct format but Excel format is getting changed.. such as table format, color , font etc... @MarkusDeibel

Comment: Per definition a CSV cannot have table format, color, font etc. . So the problem seems to be neither with your data nor with your C# code. It's a rather a question of automatically handling additional data in Excel and this would require changes in the Excel sheet/cell/macros.